# Unit test the react component generate through function that receive array of object as paramet

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, enzyme

I have a function that returns the React component with the value from an array of object, I wanna test it with enzyme.

Component

```
const overrideTimeoutValues = [
    {minutes: 0, seconds: 10},
    {minutes: 0, seconds: 15},
    {minutes: 0, seconds: 20},
    {minutes: 0, seconds: 30},
    {minutes: 1, seconds: 0},
]

export const renderMenuItems = values => values.map(({minutes, seconds}) =>
    <MenuItem
        value={`00:${minutes.toString().padStart(2,0)}:${seconds.toString().padStart(2,0)}`}
        primaryText={<FormattedMessage
            id={minutes > 0 ? 'passage.outputTimeOut.minutes': 'passage.outputTimeOut.seconds'}
            values={{seconds, minutes}}
        />}
    />)
```

Test

```
const values = [
    {minutes: 0, seconds: 10},
    {minutes: 0, seconds: 15},
    {minutes: 0, seconds: 20},
    {minutes: 0, seconds: 30},
    {minutes: 1, seconds: 0},
]

describe.only('renderMenuItems', () => {

    it('should render <MenuItem/> with correct value', () => {

        values.forEach(({minutes, seconds}) => {

            const item = renderMenuItems([{minutes, seconds}])         item.props.value.should.be.equal(`00:${minutes.toString().padStart(2,0)}:${seconds.toString().padStart(2,0)}`)

        })
    })
})
```

The problem is, I receive the [{component}] and cannot check a props value tghrouth the loop, how to test it better? Thanks.

Comment: Why you're not using enzyme wrapper to test rendered result of component?

Comment: Because I need to test function separately

Answer (score 0):

```
    it('should render <MenuItem/> with correct value', () => {
            const item = renderMenuItems(values)

            values.forEach(({minutes,seconds}, i) => {
item[i].props.value.should.be.equal(`00:${minutes.toString().padStart(2,0)}:${seconds.toString().padStart(2,0)}`)    
            })
        })
```